# Referencing the current row outer apply column within separate outer join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Recently I've been tasked with creating a report that outputs sales information by Date of Business and Hour of the Day.

Here is the query I have currently written.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS Count
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Count + 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE Count + 1 <= 23
),
ALLDATES AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startDate) AS [DOB]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [DOB])
    FROM AllDates
    WHERE [DOB] < @endDate
)
SELECT D.DOB, A.Count AS [Hour], CONCAT(A.Count, ':00') AS [DisplayHour]
    , B.OrderModeName, COALESCE(B.Sales_Total, 0) AS [Sales]
    , COALESCE(B.Comps, 0) AS Comps, COALESCE(B.Promos, 0) AS Promos
FROM CTE AS A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT DOB FROM ALLDATES) D
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DATEPART(HH, ItemDetail.TransactionTime) AS [Hour]
        , OrderMode.OrderModeName, SUM(ItemDetail.GrossPrice) Sales_Total
        , SUM(CompAmount) AS Comps, SUM(PromoAmount) AS Promos
    FROM ItemDetail
    INNER JOIN OrderMode ON OrderMode.OrderModeID = ItemDetail.OrderModeID
    WHERE ItemDetail.DOB = D.DOB /*NEED HELP HERE*/ AND LocationID IN (
        SELECT LocationID
        FROM LocationGroupMember
        WHERE LocationGroupID = '@locationGroupID'
    )
    GROUP BY ItemDetail.DOB, DATEPART(HH, ItemDetail.TransactionTime), OrderMode.OrderModeName
) AS B
ON A.Count = B.Hour
ORDER BY D.DOB, A.Count
```

Where I am struggling is being able to reference the current row's DOB column that is coming from the OUTER APPLY.

I have tried `WHERE ItemDetail.DOB = D.DOB`, however I receive an error that the identifier can't be bound. Am I correct that in understanding that the outer applied data is not visible to the subquery within the join?

Here is an example of the output I'm expecting:

```
DOB      | Hour | Display Hour | OrderModeName | Sales  | Comps | Promos
1/8/2020 | 17   | 17:00        | Order         | 163.17 |  0    |  0 <-- Sales for Hour and Order Mode present

1/8/2020 | 23   | 23:00        |               | 0      |  0    |  0 <-- No sales at all for a given hour
```

Thanks in advance for any direction and advice!

Comment: Could you show some sample data that generates the output you're after? I'm having a hard time piecing together the original data based solely on the query and two rows of output.

Comment: This `OUTER APPLY` should be a `CROSS JOIN`. This might solve your immediate issue, however it is likey that your query can be further optimized. As commented by Aaron Bertrand, you should give a wider picture of the problem.

Comment: And if you have two different order mode values in a given hour, do you want two different rows for that hour? Or are you missing a filter that explicitly confines OrderModeName to "Order"? I came up with [this fiddle as a start](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1a6d3bbe2f98aabd4ce8789878ae3657) but got stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic pattern here is to CROSS JOIN to define the result "grain" and then LEFT JOIN the fact table to populate the rows for which data exists.  EG

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 0 AS Count
UNION ALL
SELECT Count + 1
FROM CTE
WHERE Count + 1 <= 23
),
ALLDATES AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @startDate) AS [DOB]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [DOB])
    FROM AllDates
    WHERE [DOB] < @endDate
),
ALLHOURS as
(
  SELECT D.DOB, A.Count AS [Hour], CONCAT(A.Count, ':00') AS [DisplayHour]
  FROM CTE AS A
  CROSS JOIN ALLDATES D
),
ITEM_SUMMARY as
(
    SELECT DOB, DATEPART(HH, ItemDetail.TransactionTime) AS [Hour], OrderMode.OrderModeName, SUM(ItemDetail.GrossPrice) Sales_Total, SUM(CompAmount) AS Comps, SUM(PromoAmount) AS Promos
    FROM ItemDetail
    INNER JOIN OrderMode ON OrderMode.OrderModeID = ItemDetail.OrderModeID
     AND LocationID IN (SELECT LocationID FROM LocationGroupMember WHERE LocationGroupID = @locationGroupID)
    where DOB >= @startDate 
      and DOB < @endDate
    GROUP BY ItemDetail.DOB, DATEPART(HH, ItemDetail.TransactionTime), OrderMode.OrderModeName
)
select ALLHOURS.DOB, 
       ALLHOURS.Count AS [Hour], 
       CONCAT(ALLHOURS.Count, ':00') AS [DisplayHour], 
       ITEM_SUMMARY.OrderModeName, 
       COALESCE(ITEM_SUMMARY.Sales_Total, 0) AS [Sales], 
       COALESCE(ITEM_SUMMARY.Comps, 0) AS Comps, 
       COALESCE(ITEM_SUMMARY.Promos, 0) AS Promos
from ALLHOURS
LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEM_SUMMARY 
 on ITEM_SUMMARY.DOB = ALLHOURS.DOB 
 and ITEM_SUMMARY.Hour = ALLHOURS.Hour
```

Comment: Thanks David! I had started to go this route but didn't even think of also wrapping up ITEM_SUMMARY separately like you did.

I did have to change ALLHOURS.Count in the final SELECT statement to ALLHOURS.Hour since it was declared that way in the WITH.